# Bootcamp choose Windows ISO opens ISO instead of selecting ISO

Tags: bootcamp, windows

In Bootcamp I am installing Windows 10. When I select choose ISO Image, the USB that has the image shows in locations. When I select the image it opens up the folder of the ISO. It will not open in Bootcamp. I will have the choice to select from autorun.inf, boot folder, bootmgr, bootmgr.efi, efi folder, setup.exe, sources folder, support folder.

I have tried selecting several of these and some will open in Bootcamp, but all I get is the error "Need 64-bit Windows or 10 or later ISO file". I am sure the file is good I downloaded it from Microsoft and used both their installer and rufus to make 2 files. Both have same error.

I should also point out that I was running Windows 8.1 in  Bootcamp and deleted it to do a fresh install of Windows 10. I did use Bootcamp to delete the partition. This is on a Mac Pro 2013

Comment: If you insert the thumb drive into a Windows computer and look at its contents, do you see all the files you mentioned in your question or do you see an ISO file on the thumb drive?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: They are the same but in different order no ISO. The thumb drive title is ESD-USB

Comment: I just upgraded to Mojave. That is from Sierra. The Windows 8.1 was with Sierra.

Comment: Try fetching the ISO from [Microsoft's ISO Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) from your macOS partition.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have created USB flash drive Windows 10 installers by using both rufus and and the Microsoft media creation tool. Both of these methods bypass the use of the Boot Camp Assistant. You are suppose to use the Boot Camp Assistant to copy the files to the USB flash drive.

You should go to [this website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) from Microsoft and download Window 10. The last time I checked, the October 2018 update (1809) will not work with BootCamp. This only applies to older Macs that use a flash drive to install Windows. This includes your Mac. So you will probably want to download the April 2018 update (1803).

If you have High Sierra or Mojave installed on your Mac, then you can also create the USB flash drive installer without using the Boot Camp Assistant. The instructions are given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1385264/boot-camp-assistant-fails-to-create-the-usb-installer-from-the-windows-10-octobe).

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will try that this afternoon

Comment: Solved instructions worked very well. Using my mac to download windows, took me to a website only for mac. The drop down menu had the April Windows 10. Used bootcamp  to format the usb same as the instructions. Then downloaded the bootcamp drivers thru bootcamp as well. Finder helped to put it all together. When I was finished there were 2 windows volumes in bootcamp on startup. One was the installation file saved in bootcamp folder. When selected it wanted to restart Windows setup. But after a few restarts and updates it disappeared. All works very well. Thanks for the help excellent advice.